# Screw Placement for Wall Hung Cabinet

Tags: screws, cabinets, load-bearing, carpentry

I have to fix a top cabinet with no floor support to the wall.

What is the difference if I were to place the screws which hold the cabinet to the wall at the 4 corners inside the cabinet (diagram 1) vs having 2 of the corner screws shifted to the centre of the cabinet (diagram 2)?

[image: Diagrams]

Comment: Is the upper cabinet adjacent to others? They should be screwed together at the face.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which one the screws hit the studs.

Find the studs and put the screws into studs.

Miss the studs and you will be wearing the cabinet as a hat.